# Possible to resize activity blocks in Visual Studio 2010 Workflow designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation, visual-studio-designer

I'm trying to edit my TFS 2010 build templates using the Visual Studio 2010 Workflow designer. I have this nice widescreen display, and the designer insists on displaying the activity blocks in itty bitty areas. How can I resize them so I can at least read the entire display descriptions?

[image: workflow designer]

EDIT: If this annoys you too, [vote for this suggestion](https://connect.microsoft.com/wf/feedback/details/282123/feature-request-ability-to-resize-items-in-designer-mode)

Comment: I agree strongly, but this link is dead, so I've created a new suggestion for this: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4333421-support-resizing-wf-designer-components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designer doesn't support resizing activities. You can collapse/expand them or zoom into the entire workflow but that is it.

Would be a nice future feature so I suggest adding it to connect as a feature request and if you post the link I will vote for it.

Comment: good call on connect. a suggestion had already been posted (in 2007 no less) so I have posted the link

Comment: A suggestion from 2007 must be about WF3 and that is a different code base and a closed book. I would suggest creating a new one for WF4.